# How to append a char to a String in C using a function

Tags: c

I was writing a lexical analyzer in which I need to append a char to a string (a char *). For some reason, the code below is resulting in string having a value of "(null)" when I print it to stdout. The function is given below.

```
void append_char(char *buffer, char c) {
  if(buffer == NULL) {
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(buffer == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "COuld not allcocate memory to buffer\n");
    }
  } else {
    buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(buffer) + sizeof(char));
  } 
  buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1] = c;
}
```

When I run the lines

```
 char *buf = NULL;
 append_char(buf, 'a');
 append_char(buf, '\0');
 printf("buffer: %s\n", buf);
```

it prints `(null)` to stdout. How can I fix this?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is definitely wrong, because that is `sizeof(char*)` (and therefore either 4 or 8 on a modern CPU)

Comment: @UnholySheep ... or `sizeof(char*)` is 2.  100s millions of embedded processors/year in 2020 are small sub-32 bit ones.  C very popular there.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, I meant to specify modern *Desktop* CPUs (x86 and AMD64). Of course you are correct, I didn't mean to imply that there aren't other popular architectures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pass by value**

`append_char(char *buffer, char c)` does not affect the caller's `buf` in `main()`: `append_char(buf, 'a');`.  `buf` remains `NULL`.  This leads to OP's output.

**Insufficient size**

Insufficient size for the newly allocated *string*.  No room for the *null character*.

**Wrong size**

With `char *buffer`, `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, not the amount allocated beforehand.

**Lost memoery**

When `buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(buffer) + sizeof(char));` fails (`realloc()` returns `NULL`) , the original value of `buffer` is lost.  Save the result and test.

Note: OK to call `realloc(NULL, ...)`.

---

```
char *append_char(char *buffer, char c) {
  size_t old_length = buffer ? strlen(buffer) : 0;
  size_t new_length = old_length + 1; // +1 for c
  // Size needed for a string is its length + 1
  char *new_buffer = realloc(buffer, new_length + 1); // +1 for \0
  if (new_buffer == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory to buffer\n");
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
  }
  new_buffer[old_length] = c; 
  new_buffer[old_length + 1] = '\0'; 
  return new_buffer;
}

// Usage
buf = append_char(buf, 'a');
```

Comment: Now it's OK. You should let the OP know that reallocating for each and every char is not very efficient.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Your comment is good advice, yet that issue really applies to higher level code.  Here it is just _how to append a char to a string_?

Comment: Good answer, but I think that `buffer = new_buffer` (a) is unnecessary and (b) makes the code harder to understand, because `buffer` now (potentially) points to two different locations during the lifetime of the method. Just use `new_buffer` for the final three lines of the method and get rid of the assignment.

Comment: @Heinzi Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your program:

1. `buffer` is a local variable of `append_char()`. As soon as this function returns, the `buffer` variable becomes unusable. You need to pass in the address of `buffer` to write the address returned by `malloc()` and `realloc()` to `buffer`.
2. `buf` is a pointer to a `char`. `sizeof (buf)` does *not* depend on the number of characters in `buf`.
3. You do not check the return value from `realloc()`.
4. You are not allocating space for the NUL terminator.
5. You do not call `free()` after you are done.

Here is one way to achieve what you are trying to do (although I am not trying to fix *all* the problems I mentioned above):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append_char(char **buffer, char c) {
        if(*buffer == NULL) {
                if((*buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1)) == NULL) { /* + 1 for the NUL terminator */
                        fprintf(stderr, "COuld not allcocate memory to buffer\n");
                        return;
                }
                (*buffer)[0] = (*buffer)[1] = '\0';
        } else {
                *buffer = realloc(*buffer, strlen(*buffer) + sizeof(char) + 1 /* for the NUL terminator */);
        }
        (*buffer)[strlen(*buffer) + 1] = '\0';
        (*buffer)[strlen(*buffer)] = c;       
}

int main(void)
{
        char *buf = NULL;
        append_char(&buf, 'a');
        append_char(&buf, '\0');
        printf("buffer: %s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: That code does not work, it crashes on my platform

Comment: @Jabberwocky Could you please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: Ahh! Good catch @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have just swapped those two lines.